# GTM Click Element Image instead of Link

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've got a pretty much standard image link of type

```
<a href="" class="someClass"><img src="..."></a>
```

I have added a trigger in GTM based on the class of 'someClass' and a click on the image/link doesn't fire the trigger. I looked into the GTM preview debug panel and the click event is fired on the image, not on the link.

[image]

Is there a way to make a trigger fire without moving the class from  to the ?

Comment: The reason seems to be event not bubbling, but it bubbles OK if I add a listener to the link with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a css ::after attached to the link.

The solution was to set z-index to -1 on the image.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution is get a parent in a Macross, and them select the desire value, in this case i get a custom Attr

```
function()
    {
        try 
        {
            if ({{Click Element}}.parentNode) 
            {
                return {{Click Element}}.parentNode.getAttribute("data-url");
            }
        }
        catch(err) 
        {
            return undefined;
        }

    return undefined;
}
```

You can base the rules with the parent, or the grand parent if you nrrf

Answer (score 0):

You can add the trigger as `.someClass img` to `Click Element > Matches CSS Selector`